# Stylesheet doesn't load while render_to_string is preparing page wor wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I'm using wicked_pdf to generate pdf reports.
Downloading from page works great.

Now I try to send pdf as mail attachment without saving file.

reports_controller.rb

```
def send_personal_report
  pdf_html = render_to_string(template:'personal.pdf', layout: 'pdf.html')
  pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(pdf_html)
  UserMailer.report_email(pdf).deliver_now
end
```

layouts/pdf.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "custom" %>
<title>Отчет</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
```

stylesheets/custom.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

user_mailer.rb

```
def report_email(pdf) 
  attachments['report.pdf'] = {mime_type: 'application/pdf', content: pdf}
  mail(to: 'test@domain.com', subject: 'Report')
end
```

but after all my attachment in email is just a raw HTML.

Comment: Could you show us code for the `report_email` method?

Comment: @bitsapien sure, I've updated question.

Comment: You need to save the pdf to a file to attach it.

Comment: @CAmador no, you don't )

Answer (score 0):

Try setting format (assuming you have html.erb and text.erb templates):

```rb
def report_email(pdf) 
  #attachments['report.pdf'] = {mime_type: 'application/pdf', content: pdf}
  mail(to: 'test@domain.com', subject: 'Report') do |f|
    f.text
    f.html
    f.pdf do
      attachments['report.pdf'] = {mime_type: 'application/pdf', content: pdf}
    end
  end
end
```